# max_connections_per_hour get count of active connections

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have limit of 20 000 connections per hour. I guess it is more than enough.
Theese days i have a problem that our presentation randomly exceeds this limit.

Im not able to find a connection loop because i cannot view count of this connections.

Is there a way how to show/get this number? I found some tricks.
For ex.

```
show processlist
```

or

```
SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';
```

But results of this commands are ok. First one show me one process and second one shows about 20 threads.

Did anybody know if is possible to view number of connections remains to exceeds this limit?

Comment: What is it you want to achieve? I guess it's identifiying the php code (if it exists) that establishes the excess connections? 20000/h is more than 5 per second.

Comment: Not exactly. I want to know if mysql have any statistict about this active connectins which causes that error with max_connections_per_hour. Im blind about finding the php code (if it exists) which makes so many connections because i dont know realtime number of theese connections.

Comment: If there is such access to the counter variable it probably won't help you finding the code as the MySQL server has no clue about what code creates the connection. It only knows about the server from which the connection originates and the user credentials used to authenticate. I'd say [profiling](http://www.sitepoint.com/debugging-and-profiling-php-with-xdebug/) looks more fruitful.